# Inapporative use of Infinite Loop in C

Tags: c

```
int powi(int a,int b)
{
      if(b<0)      
        return 1 / powi (a,-b);
      else if(b==0)
        return 1;
      else if(b==1)
        return a;
      else
        return a*powi(a,b-1);

}

int factorial(int number)
{
    int x,fac;
    /* numberi scanfle istemis ona gore dusun */
    fac=1;

    for(x = 1; x <= number; x++)
   {
      if (number >= 0)
         fac = fac * x;
      else
         fac=1;
   }
return 0;
}


void getInputs(int *degree,int *n,int *exit)
{
    scanf("%d %d",degree,n);
    if(*degree=='e')
        *exit=1;
    else
        *exit=0;

}

double cosine(int degree,int n)
{
#define pi 3.14
int sum,i;
    if(degree<360 && degree>-1)
        degree=(degree*pi)/180;
    else if(degree<0)
        {   do
                { degree=degree+360;
                } while(degree<0);
        degree=(degree*pi)/180;
        }
    else
        {
        degree=degree%360;  
        degree=(degree*pi)/180;
        }

for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)

    {   
        sum=0;
        sum=sum+powi(-1,n)*powi(degree,2*n)/factorial(2*n);


    }   

return 0;

}

double sine(int degree,int n)
{
int i,sum;
#define pi 3.14
    if(degree<360 && degree>-1)
        degree=(degree*pi)/180;
    else if(degree<0)
        {   do
                { degree=degree+360;
                } while(degree<0);
        degree=(degree*pi)/180;
        }
    else {
        degree=degree%360;  
        degree=(degree*pi)/180;
        }

for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)

    {
    sum=0;
        sum=sum+powi(-1,n)*powi(degree,2*n+1)/factorial(2*n+1);
    }
return 0;

}
```

Hi everyone,i have this little code of mine which trying to calculate sin and cos via Taylor and Maclorin series.But seems like i messed up with something.
This is basic code without main function For EX: when i try to call sin(30,4) it gives an infinite loop.I really cant find where it got stuck into it.

A little help would appriciated.
Thank your for your time.

Comment: That's not called "little code". It's too much in fact.

Comment: Use `double`s instead of `int`s.

Comment: just glancing over that looks more like infinite recursion than infinite loop. Check powi carefully for issues, as all the other loops look like they should terminate just fine.

Comment: There is a lot of problems. but The cause of the infinite loop seems like `getInputs`.

Comment: @alain It didnt worked out. Checking other suggestions though i basically rewrote entire powi still nothing is different. Strange enough

Comment: There are too many problems in your program. See [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Asides: Do you really enter `101` (ASCII for `'e'`) to exit the program? Strangely, you don't even use the `exit` variable later. Also `int factorial()` seems to return an inadequate type for its purpose. As you are using factorial to calculate trigonometry functions I suggest you use a `double` type.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes my assigments says that. "... The function named getInputs will wait for user to enter the degree and n value. If ‘E’ is entered instead, the exit variable will be 1, otherwise 0. ..."

Comment: But the format specifier is `%d` which refuses non-numeric entry.

Comment: `#define pi 3.14` ?? How far are you going with that?

Comment: But thats the point? user shouldnt enter non numberic number , if user enters 'E' then program exit variable will be 1.

Comment: @WeatherVane not sure what you meant by "#define pi 3.14 how far.."  I mean we arent allowed to use pi so i defined it. What seems to be problem with that?

Comment: ["How I want a drink, alcoholic of course, after the heavy lectures involving quantum mechanics,"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiWordplay.html) 3.14 is a very rough approximation of pi, even slightly worse than 22/7, but better than 3.

Comment: What is the use of commenting if you don't read it? The format specifer `%d` ***will NOT read*** the entry `E`. Also, I suggest using more significance with `#define pi 3.14159265358979323846`. Work as accurately as you can.

Comment: @MOehm `pi` very nearly *was* `3` [by law](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5880792/the-eccentric-crank-who-tried-to-legislate-the-value-of-pi)

Comment: @WeatherVane: Integer arithmetic for the win! (That also explains why the OP tries to read _e_ = 2.718... ≈ 3 with the `%d` format specifier.)

Comment: @MOehm I think π is so close to *e* that they should be interchangeable. **π == *e*** rules OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double sum=0;
for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
{
    sum=sum+(double)(powi(-1,n)*powi(degree,2*n+1))/factorial(2*n+1);
}
```

return sum;

Try this

1. u need to declare sum as double
2. when dividing a long expression whoose output might be a a decimal no. u should typecast it to float or double
3. return sum rather then 0